# how to set my android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item to a white font?

Tags: android

I have a problem, I use a `Spinner` in my `ActionBar`:

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

the problem is, that I'm using the dark action bar theme. So my font is black and the action bar is also black.

How can I change the font of the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` to white? Or even better: to the default action bar font color?

Comment: why not just create your own custom layout?

Comment: because I want to use as much as already existing code as possible

Comment: that view is an android resource, you cannot change it

Comment: ok now I made my own layout. Post your comment as a answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the view is an android resource you cannot change is, create your own layout and change what you want. you can always find that resource file, copy the xml and change what you want in your own file